# Android dataBinding - How to get resource id of a View in xml

Tags: android, data-binding

In Android Studio my data binding itself works and is set up fine. I have a boolean defined like this:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="showAds">false</bool>
</resources>
```

and in a layout.xml file i would like to referenced this boolean (which works fine) but i want to assign a id based on this boolean. Let me show you what i am trying to accomplish:

I have a button that is in a relativeLayout tag and depending on this boolean i would like to reposition the button. So I have this:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/startButton"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="64dip"
   ****************
   android:layout_below="@{@bool/showAds ? @+id/adone : @+id/title_main}"
   ****************
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:textColor="#0080FF"
   android:text="@string/start_btn_title" />
```

See what i want to to do? I want to layout the button below a layout called adone if the showAds boolean is true, otherwise place it below a layout called title_main.  Whats the syntax for this as what I have here is not compiling. I get a compile error:

> expression expected after the second @ sign

Comment: Try removing the `+` sign from both options, giving you `@{@bool/showAds ? @+id/adone : @+id/title_main}`, and see if that works. You'll need the `+` sign on the IDs in the actual views themselves.

Comment: thanks for the help, actually http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_below says i need the "+ sign" but i removed it anyway and then i get a error of " Error:(119, 33) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_below' with parameter type int. "  so looks like its seeing it as a int .     btw, it looks like this after applying your comments:  android:layout_below="@{@bool/showAds ? @id/adone : @id/title_main}"

Comment: The `+` is needed somewhere, ideally on the first occurrence of the ID. My guess is that the data binding expression language can't handle defining new IDs, which is why removing the `+` moved you forward. Next test: `@{@id/adone}`. If that compiles (though it won't give you what you want), then the ternary operator is somehow losing the fact that these are ID resources. If this does not compile, then it may be something tied to `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` attributes.

Comment: can i do a if condition without elvis operator ? The "next test" also does not work.  It cant recognize it as an expression when i do that.

Comment: Then I don't think the problem is the operator, but rather with `layout_below`, but that's just my educated guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above is the same problem as in [How to get dimensions from dimens.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832578/android-databinding-how-to-get-dimensions-from-dimens-xml)

None of the `LayoutParams` attributes have built-in support. As answered in the linked article, data binding of `LayoutParams` was thought to be too easy to abuse so it was left out of the built-in `BindingAdapters`. You are not abusing it, so you should add your own.

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_below")
public static void setLayoutBelow(View view, int oldTargetId, int newTargetId) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
        view.getLayoutParams();
    if (oldTargetId != 0) {
        // remove the previous rule
        layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
    }
    if (newTargetId != 0) {
        // add new rule
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, newTargetId);
    }
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

As an aside, the @+id/adone in the binding syntax will not create the id. You should create the id in the View you're binding to.